# Regex to capture to specific percent/decimals

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape for interest rates in multiple sites. The data is pretty unstructured but close enough in form. What I want to capture:

**x.xx% to xx.xx%**

Examples of what the data looks like:

*All loans made by WebBank, Member FDIC. Your actual rate depends upon credit score, loan amount, loan term, and credit usage & history. The **APR ranges from 5.98% to 35.89%**. For example, you could receive a loan of $6,000 with an interest rate of 7.99% and a 5.00% origination fee of $300 for an APR of 11.51%. In this example, you will receive $5,700 and will make 36 monthly payments of $187.99. The total amount repayable will be $6,767.64. Your APR will be determined based on your credit at time of application. The origination fee ranges from 1% to 6% and the average origination fee is 5.49% as of Q1 2017. There is no down payment and there is never a prepayment penalty. Closing of your loan is contingent upon your agreement of all the required agreements and disclosures on the www.lendingclub.com website. All loans via LendingClub have a minimum repayment term of 36 months or longer.*

**3.09% – 14.24%***

*Fixed rates:
**6.99% to 24.99% APR**
Lock in your rate. Your monthly payment will never change.*

I've bolded what I wanted to capture. My current regex looks like this:

```
(re.findall('(?i)(\d\.\d\d% (?:to|-) \d\d\.\d\d%)
```

The actual quote looks like:

```
plcompetitors = ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans',
                'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans',
                'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/',
                'https://www.lightstream.com/',
                'https://www.prosper.com/']

#cycle through links in array until it finds APR rates/fixed or variable using regex
for link in plcompetitors:
    cdate = datetime.date.today()
    l = r.get(link)
    l.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data = l.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
    for n in paragraph:
        matches = []
        matches.extend(re.findall('(?i)(\d\.\d\d% (?:to|-) \d\d\.\d\d%)', n.string))
        matches.append(cdate.isoformat())
        matches.append(link)
        print(matches)
    paragraph.append(cdate.isoformat())
    paragraph.append(link)
```

New Output:

```
['5.98% to 35.89%', '2018-06-22', 'https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans']
['6.99% to 24.99%', '6.99% to 24.99%', '6.99% to 24.99%', '6.99% to 24.99%', '2018-06-22', 'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['6.99% to 24.99%', '2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.lightstream.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
['2018-06-22', 'https://www.prosper.com/']
```

Comment: Are you sure that output comes from a match of that  regex?

Comment: does `\d{1}.\d{2}% to \d{2}.\d{2}%` does the trick?

Comment: Also you said you want to capture *x.xx% to xx.xx%* but you made APR and some other words bold.

Comment: @revo that output matches a specific string within that output and ends up pulling the entire paragraph instead of just capturing the string within the paragraph. As for the extra bolded words I was trying to show how the strings differed from each other within the piece of information I wanted. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then try `re.findall(r'(?i)(\b\d\.\d\d% (?:to|-) \d\d\.\d\d%)', str)`

Comment: Hmm... it's still pulling the entire paragraph. Could this potentially be happening because I am trying to parse out that string while scraping the site in beautiful soup?

Comment: also it seems like the or operator ( "|" ) isn't working because it is only pulling the websites that have "to" between the interest rates and not the "-" websites. Should I change my approach and scrape all the relevant paragraphs and then pull the substrings out from there?

Comment: @dtrinh You have already understood the problem is not with your regex, as `\d{1,2}%` does not match letters, spaces... it only matches 1 or 2 digits and a `%` after them. So, post the faulty code if you want our help. Else, you are on your own now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the code to the post and updated the regex provided

Comment: Ok, you have `paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('(?i)(\d\.\d\d% (?:to|-) \d\d\.\d\d%)'))` - it just gets all the nodes with that pattern. Try something like `matches=[]`, `for n in paragraph:`, `matches.extend(re.findall(pattern, n.string))`

Comment: So I added my updated code. The output looks great. You're idea worked like a charm now I just have questions so I can refine the output. The new output pulls multiple entries from the same url, one line will have the info i want and the rest are basically nulls. Is there a reason for this? Also is there a reason why the | ("or") operator isn't working? It's only matching with the patterns that contain "to" between the numbers even though it should look for "-" as well? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what the problem is now and can't post an answer. Does the regex match fewer strings? Try https://regex101.com/r/N95GeJ/1

Comment: I'll take a look at that. I am getting more matches than before which is good. Just need to refine the matches for the other websites now. Thanks for all your help @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I will post an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('(?i)(\d\.\d\d% (?:to|-) \d\d\.\d\d%)'))` line gets all the nodes with values matching your pattern. You need to actually *extract* the matches from these paragraphs.

Use something like

```
matches=[]
for n in paragraph:
    matches.extend(re.findall(pattern, n.string))
```

As for the pattern itself, you may use

```
(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N95GeJ/1). Details:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive maching is ON
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - 1+ digits that is optionally followed with `.` and 1+ digits
- `%` - a `%` sign
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:to|-)` - `to` or `-`
- `\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%` - see above (in short, whitespace(s), an int or float value followed with `%`).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: In light of your comment
**Run the following in Python3 which should processes your example string in ASCII at default**:

**Input**

```
import re

input = '''All loans made by WebBank, Member FDIC. Your actual rate depends upon credit score, loan amount, loan term, and credit usage & history. The APR ranges from 5.98% to 35.89%. For example, you could receive a loan of $6,000 with an interest rate of 7.99% and a 5.00% origination fee of $300 for an APR of 11.51%. In this example, you will receive $5,700 and will make 36 monthly payments of $187.99. The total amount repayable will be $6,767.64. Your APR will be determined based on your credit at time of application. The origination fee ranges from 1% to 6% and the average origination fee is 5.49% as of Q1 2017. There is no down payment and there is never a prepayment penalty. Closing of your loan is contingent upon your agreement of all the required agreements and disclosures on the www.lendingclub.com website. All loans via LendingClub have a minimum repayment term of 36 months or longer.

3.09% – 14.24%*

Fixed rates: 6.99% to 24.99% APR Lock in your rate. Your monthly payment will never change.'''
#Non-specific regex (I'm cheating)
output = re.findall('[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%[\S\s]{0,5}[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%', input)
print('output:')
print(output)

#More specific -- you can edit this in several ways
output_1 = re.findall('[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%[to\-\s]+[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%', input)
print('\noutput_1:')
print(output_1)

#What you need if you copy+paste from Stack into Python2.7.X
output_2 = re.findall('[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%[\s]*[to|\-|\xe2\x80\x93]+[\s]*[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]+%', input)
print('\noutput_2 (Python2.X):')
print(output_2)
```

**Output**

```
output:
['5.98% to 35.89%', '3.09% - 14.24%', '6.99% to 24.99%']

output_1:
['5.98% to 35.89%', '3.09% - 14.24%', '6.99% to 24.99%']

output_2 (Python2.X)::
['5.98% to 35.89%', '3.09% \xe2\x80\x93 14.24%', '6.99% to 24.99%']
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. If you take a look at the comments the one from Wiktor is similar to what you are trying to do but a bit more dynamic as it can loop through a list. Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Not sure I totally understand the question yet. But hopefully another can provide a better answer. Still what are you trying to capture specifically? Can you include a "list" of output so I can get a better idea.

Comment: Basically I want to use regular expression to grab the interest rates on the 5 websites I have listed. I updated my post above with the updated code/output. The outputs with the "%" have the exact outputs I want. But now I am trying to figure out why there are so many outputs with only 5 websites, and why my regex is ignoring the or operator I have in place on there.